# In ggplot2 and facet_wrap, how to remove all margins and padding yet keep strip.text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

This might primarily be a result of me misunderstanding how `panel.margin = unit(...)` works in the `theme()` function...but I'm unable to customize margins in facet_wrap the way that I'd like. Basically, I want a facet_grid that looks like this, with facet text (i.e. `strip.text`) inset in each facet and no spcaing between each facet:

(I've left in the pink borders to show the dimensions of each facet)

[image: The ideal final product]

So here's the code so far.

To set up the data and plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = qsec), stat = 'identity') +
  facet_wrap( ~ carb, ncol = 3)

mytheme <- theme_minimal() + theme(
  axis.text.x = element_blank(),
  axis.text.y = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  axis.title = element_blank(),
  panel.margin = unit(0, "lines"),
  panel.border = element_rect(colour = rgb(1.0, 0, 0, 0.5), fill=NA, size=1)
)
```

The standard plot

```
 p + mytheme
```

[image: just a standard plot]

Removing the strip.text completely

```
p + mytheme + theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image: no strip text]

Adding the strip.text and insetting it

```
p + mytheme +
     theme(strip.text = element_text(size = rel(3.0), vjust = -4.0))
```

[image: test grid inset text]

The re-inclusion of strip.text (and the increased relative size) increases the vertical margin between the two rows. So at this point, I don't know how to close the vertical gap between the top and bottom rows.

Too much negative margin

```
p + mytheme +
    theme(strip.text = element_text(size = rel(3.0), vjust = -4.0), 
          panel.margin = unit(c(-2, -2), "lines"))
```

[image: Too much negative margin]

So how do I target just the panel.margin between the two rows?

**Edit:** Additional information. The space between the rows appears to be `strip.background`:

```
p + mytheme +
        theme(strip.text = element_text(size = rel(3.0), vjust = -4.0),
              panel.margin = unit(-1, "lines"),
              strip.background = element_rect(fill = rgb(0, 1.0, 0, 0.2)))
```

[image]

Comment: If you use `panel.margin.y = unit(-2, "lines")`, you only decrease the space between rows. Is that what you were looking for or was there something else?

Comment: @maj ...it...can't be that simple...but it was. I guess I missed it in the documentation somewhere. Can you repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @maj at my system I need `panel.margin.y = unit(-0.5, "lines")` to get the desired result

Comment: @Jaap Okay, I'm wondering why that is. Are you using RStudio? If not, might the definition of "lines" be the problem, i.e. your viewport uses other default values? - "Lines of text. Locations and dimensions are in terms of multiples of the default text size of the viewport (as specified by the viewport's fontsize and lineheight)."

Comment: @maj I have changed your answer a bit to better reflect the interaction with the settings in `strip.text`.

Comment: @Jaap I see now, thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Among the list of possible arguments to `theme()`, there is not only `panel.margin` ("margin around facet panels (unit)", see [`?theme`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html)), but conveniently, you can also access one of the axes at a time, with `panel.margin.x` and `panel.margin.y` respectively ("horizontal/vertical margin around facet panels (unit; inherits from panel.margin)").

Therefore, while decreasing the margin below zero feels a bit like a hack, something like the following will do the job (you might have to adjust the value a little - `unit(-2, "lines")` worked best for me):

```
p + theme(strip.text = element_text(size = rel(3.0), vjust = -4.0), 
          panel.margin.y = unit(-2, "lines"))
```

If you use `strip.text = element_blank()`, then you should probably use `panel.margin.y = unit(-0.5, "lines")`.