# position_stack() changes data when used with geom_line() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to stack several geom_line() plots one above the other. However they appeared with changed data.

Here is an example:

```
# make 3 data.frame with some random data
x <- seq(5, 15, length = 1000)
data1 <- data.frame(x = x, y = dnorm(x, mean = 10, sd = 3), sample = "1")
data2 <- data.frame(x = x, y = dnorm(x, mean = 7.5, sd = 3), sample = "2")
data3 <- data.frame(x = x, y = dnorm(x, mean = 12.5, sd = 1), sample = "3")

# bind data
data <- bind_rows(data1, data2, data3)

# plot data without stacking
plot.data <- data %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = sample)) + geom_line()

# plot data with stacking
plot.data <- data %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = sample)) + geom_line(position = position_stack(vjust = 1, reverse = T))
```

The plot without stacking looks like this:

[image: plot without stacking]

The plot with stacking looks like this:

[image: plot with stacking]

So it seems that position_stack sums the data, not shifts them to some constnant value, which is not expected behaviour for geom_line in my opinion. Could you suggest how to make the plots to be just shifted one above the other?

Comment: Is this an acceptable alternative? :) `ggplot(data, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color=sample)) + geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~sample, ncol=1)`

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what `position_stack` is supposed to do! It literally stacks the lines on top of each other, more obviously seen when you use `geom_area`. I agree with Johnny that facetting is probably what you want!

Comment: @JonnyPhelps thanks for your answer, but this is not exactly what I want. Actually I want to compare several spectra and it is easier to do this when they are on the same plot but shifted by some y value, not on different plots with extra space used by ggplot's facet_wrap

Comment: @Axeman thanks for clarification. Seems that I'm spoiled by Origin software where stacking means shifting graphs by const value, not summing them up :) as far as I understood I need to do this by hand in R

Comment: You can remove a lot of the space with facet_wrap e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426951/in-ggplot2-and-facet-wrap-how-to-remove-all-margins-and-padding-yet-keep-strip