# Cannot adjust grid margin in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart, visualization

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426951/in-ggplot2-and-facet-wrap-how-to-remove-all-margins-and-padding-yet-keep-strip), but it's not working. My grids are too small. I would like to mostly, **increase the grid width** so that we can see all bars and their respective n/proportions (in blue), and their labels won't overlap anymore (in red). **How can I do that?**

- Plot:

[image: plot]

**I need to**:

- A) Increase the grids' width (avoid cutting ns and proportions) (in blue)
- B) avoid overlapping the labels (in red). Thanks in advance.
- My code:

```
### packages:


library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(viridis)
library(tidyquant) # theme function:
library(cowplot) # Join plots
library(ggpattern)
library(ggtext) ## use markdown inside ggplot2

### plot:
  
### set fonts:
  
library(showtext)
  
sysfonts::font_add_google("Montserrat", family = "Mont")
t3 <- "Mont"

## Allows the use of the downloaded Google Font (from Ícaro)
## To see the results updated, it's needed to call windows() or save the image

showtext::showtext_opts(dpi = 300)
showtext::showtext_auto()

  
### set colors:
  
  
g1 <- c('yellow', 'darkgrey')
names(g1) <- c('Separated',
               'Together')
### plot it:
  
myPlot <- myData %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = prop, x = as.ordered(Q40), fill = as.ordered(Q40), pattern = Q9)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           width = 0.9) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = g1,
                    name = NULL) +
  ### dont change:
  geom_bar_pattern(stat = "identity",
                   width = 0.9,
                   color = "black",
                   pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_angle = 45,
                   pattern_density = 0.35, # 0.35
                   pattern_spacing = 0.1, # 0.025
                   pattern_alpha = 0.3,
                   show.legend = FALSE, # omit pattern from legend
                   pattern_shape = 'convex3') +  #triangule
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c('Bilíngue' = 'crosshatch'),
                       guide = 'none') +
  geom_text(aes(label = str_glue('{round(prop, 1.5)} %')),
            nudge_y = 5,
            vjust = 0.4,
            #   nudge_x = 0.05,
            size = 5) + 
  geom_label(aes(label= str_glue('n = {n}')),
             size = 5,
             nudge_x = 0.3,
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent_format(scale = 1)) +
  
  
  
  labs(x = "Tipe of Q40",
       y = 'Proportion (%)') +
  facet_grid(~ LEVEL, scales="free_x") +
  theme_tq() +
  theme( 
    
    text = element_text(family = t3,
                        size = 4.5),
    
    
    panel.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'), #transparent panel bg
    plot.background = element_rect(fill='transparent', color=NA), #transparent plot bg
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), #remove major gridlines
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), #remove minor gridlines
    
    legend.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'), #transparent legend bg
    legend.box.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'), #transparent legend panel
    legend.box.margin = margin(t = 2, r = 1, b = 2, l = 1),
    
    plot.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 15, b = 0, l = 15),
    
    
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.box.spacing = unit('0.5', "cm"),
    legend.title=element_text(size = 25),
    #   legend.margin = margin(t = 2, r = 1, b = 2, l = 1),
    
    legend.text=element_text(size=20), 
    
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -1.5,
                                size=20), # change 'X legend label'
    
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8.5,  # legend of ticks points 
                               angle = 0,
                               hjust = 0.5, 
                               face = "bold",
    ), # legenda de baixo: axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"), axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    
    
    axis.title.y =  element_text(size=20,
                                 margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 10)), # change 'proporção'
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15,
                               face = "bold",
                               hjust = 1),
    
    ### grid: ## HELPPP!!!
    
    strip.text.x = element_text(face = "bold",
                                family = t3,
                                size = 13,
                                colour = 'yellow'),
    strip.background = element_rect(size = 25,
                                    fill = '#3A4388'),
    
    # panel.margin = unit(-5, "lines"), # new : panel.spacing ## not working
    #  strip.switch.pad.grid = unit(20, "cm") # not working
    
    
  )


ggsave('plots/', myPlot, bg='transparent', dpi = 300)
```

- data:

```
structure(list(Q40 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Separated", "Together"), class = "factor"), 
    Q9 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Extracurricular", 
    "CH Estendida", "Bilíngue", "Internacional"), class = "factor"), 
    n = c(6L, 17L, 7L, 11L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L), prop = c(26.09, 
    73.91, 38.89, 61.11, 38.89, 61.11, 50, 50, 50, 50), sd = c(0.34, 
    0.34, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0, 0, 0, 0), LEVEL = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Level One", 
    "Level Two", "Level Threee", "Level Four", "Level Five"), class = "factor")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    Q9 = structure(3L, .Label = c("Extracurricular", "CH Estendida", 
    "Bilíngue", "Internacional"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question.. but a good alternative here is to use horizontal bars (with `coord_flip()`) which will make comparisons easier and make the text fit better.

Comment: I saw you saving the plot at the end, so setting a larger `ggsave(width = )` value might be a quick hack